# spring aspect not getting fired on getConnection

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I am trying to intercept the getConnection call in spring 3.2.3

```
@Component
@Aspect
@Order(value = 1)
public class ConnectionAspect {

    //@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(java.sql.Connection javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection(..))", returning = "connection")
    @Around("execution(java.sql.Connection javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection(..))")
    public Connection prepare(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        return MyConnectionProxy.newInstance((Connection) pjp.proceed(pjp.getArgs()));
    }

}
```

This aspect does not invoked on calling getConnection . 
Is there any mistake in the point cut definition **execution(java.sql.Connection javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection(..))**

Comment: With Spring AOP you can only advise spring managed beans. Are your `DataSource` instances spring managed beans?

Comment: javax.sql.DataSource is not spring managed .I am using spring with jpa repositories . The connection is obtained from the tomcat connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

Spring AOP can only advise spring managed beans. If your `DataSource` instances are not spring managed beans, you won't be able to achieve your goal with Spring AOP.

I would try to solve this issue by creating some kind of delegating proxy around the container provided DataSource, and make it a bean managed by spring. It turns out there's actually a class intended in Spring specifically for this purpose. It's called [`DelegatingDataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DelegatingDataSource.html). You only need to subclass this class, ovverride the `getConnection()` method (or whichever other method's behavior you need to affect), set it up for delegating to the container provided `DataSource`, and making it a spring managed bean and you're good to go.

Someting along this example should do it:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    public static class MySpecialDataSource extends DelegatingDataSource {

        public MySpecialDataSource(DataSource delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        @Override
        public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
            return super.getConnection();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(@Autowired DataSource containerDataSource) {
        return new MySpecialDataSource(containerDataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name="containerDataSource")
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean containerDataSource() {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean factoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJndiName("jdbc/MyDataSource");
        return factoryBean;
    }

}
```

The best thing is that you didn't even need Spring AOP or AspectJ for that.

Comment: I tried to add above snippet for "DelegatingDataSource".. but during application startup - i am getting BeanCurrentlyInCreationException. Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: ErrorStackTrace:: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Comment: @Karthikeyan yes, I think you have a circular dependency problem. Solve that and try again.