# DelegatingDataSource Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, aop, jndi, spring-aop

I am trying to implement Spring Boot AOP for data-source pointcut - where before running any query I need to set client context in DB connection.

I was trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355965/spring-aspect-not-getting-fired-on-getconnection) approach of using DelegatingDataSource. But I am getting below error during server startup

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Please let me know DeletegatingDatasource for JNDI based DB lookup.

Edit 1: AOP - I tried to add pointcut `execution(public * javax.sql.DataSource+.getConnection(..))`. This works only when Spring datasource is used with username/password. Once i deploy in Jboss with JNDI I am getting `WildFlyDataSource` Proxy error.  So, instead of AOP approach I thought of using `DelegatingDatasource`

```
   // AOP Example

    @Pointcut("execution(public * javax.sql.DataSource+.getConnection(..))")
    void prepareConnectionPointcut() {
        logger.debug("prepareConnectionPointcut");
    }
    
    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "prepareConnectionPointcut()", returning = "connection")
    void afterPrepareConnection(Connection connection) {
        // Set context in Connection - return same connection for query execution
    }
```

But when i deploy this code in JBoss - I am getting WildFlyDataSource datasource bean creation error.

> Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not
> generate CGLIB subclass of class
> org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource:
> Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a
> non-visible class; nested exception is
> org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError-->org/jboss/as/connector/subsystems/datasources/WildFlyDataSource

I have also added proxyTargetClass flag during initialization

> @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(**proxyTargetClass** = true)

Comment: That will obviously not work, as you are defining the data source yourself and have a dependency on it it is a circular dependency. Also not sure why you would call this AOP as it is just a proxy. Use a `BeanPostProcessor` to wrap an existing `DataSource` with your delegating implementation.

Comment: @Deinum: Thanks for your response. I have added reason for terming AOP. Will BeanPostProcessor be called whenever datasource bean is called ? Meaning whenever some query is executed in DAO (through entitymanager.createNativeQuery or Repository.find ?

Comment: I suggest you readup on what a `BeanPostProcessor` is and does.

Comment: I tried to implement `BeanPostProcessor` & understand its execution. It is called first time during initialization or bean. But what i am looking is to aspect pointcut every time before running any queries/storedprocedure to set DB session context.  Equivalent of [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/old-docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/orcl.connection.html) in spring boot

Comment: You clearly don't understand the usage of `BeanPostProcessor` and how to combine it with `DelegatingDataSourc`. Use the `BeanPostProcessor` to wrap the existing datasource with a delegating one, which executes your logic in the `getCOnnection` method. You don't need to use app for this.

Comment: Thanks for your help @M.Deinum. I am able to implement your suggestion & is working fine in both JBoss JNDI based deployment & Spring Boot Datasource URL based connection. I will update my snippet as answer for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @M.Deinum for recommendation of using `BeanPostProcessor` & Implement `DelegatingDatasource` for setting client info. Please find snippet below which i have implemented to accomplish [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/old-docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/orcl.connection.html) in Spring Boot which works well with JBoos JNDI based connection or Spring Boot URL Datasource connection.

```
@Component
public class MyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyBeanPostProcessor.class);

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {

        if (bean instanceof DataSource) {
            // Check DataSource bean initialization & enclose it with DelegatingDataSource 
            logger.debug("MyBeanPostProcessor:: postProcessAfterInitialization:: DataSource");

            DataSource beanDs = (DataSource) bean;
            return new MyDelegateDS(beanDs);
        }

        return BeanPostProcessor.super.postProcessAfterInitialization(bean, beanName);
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof DataSource) {
            logger.debug("MyBeanPostProcessor:: postProcessBeforeInitialization:: DataSource");
        }

        logger.debug("MyBeanPostProcessor:: postProcessBeforeInitialization:: " + beanName);

        return BeanPostProcessor.super.postProcessBeforeInitialization(bean, beanName);
    }

}
```

My implementation of `DelegatingDataSource` to handle each user request to set client context in DB connection session

```
 public class MyDelegateDS extends DelegatingDataSource {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyDelegateDS.class);

    public MyDelegateDS(DataSource delegate) {
        super(delegate);
        logger.debug("MyDelegateDS:: constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        logger.debug("MyDelegateDS:: getConnection");

        // To do this context only for user Request - to avoid this during Server initialization
        if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null
                && ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest() != null) {

            logger.debug("MyDelegateDS:: getConnection: valid user request");

            HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
                    .getRequest();
                    
            // Checking each user request & calling SP to set client context before invoking actual native query/SP
        }

        logger.debug("MyDelegateDS:: getConnection: Not User Request");

        return super.getConnection();
    }

}
```

Hope this is helpful for someone facing same problem